# Одновременная работа с несколькими клиентами

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь написать некоторое подобие чата на c# с использованием windows form. Есть два приложения - сервер и клиент. Сервер стартует на ip 127.0.0.1 и порте 8085. Хранит список подключений кастомного класса, который инициализируется именем, стримом и id. То есть получается, что клиент посылает сообщения вида operation/имя. При коннекте к серверу, клиент отправляет строку connect/nickname. Сервер создает объект клиента, связывает его со стримом и ником, и добавляет в список клиентов вот так

```
 public void listenClient()
        {

            TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i = 0;

            while (true)
            {

                string str;
                string message;

                str = getMessage(stream);
                string[] words = str.Split('/');
                string command = words[1];
                string nickname = words[2];

                if (command == "connect")
                {
                    ClientClass tmp = new ClientClass(nickname, stream);
                    addConnection(tmp);
                }

                if (command == "close")
                {
                    delConnection(nickname);
                    break;

                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);


                //client.Close();

            }
}
```

Если клиент отправляет close то он удаляется из списка и его "прослушивание" прекращается. Что бы как-то отслеживать работу сервера, я создал форму listbox, у сервера создал член класса `static ListBox listBox;` По нажатию кнопки старт, я отправляю форму в метод класса и он инициализируется формой и стартует:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           server.initForm(listBox1);
           server.start();
           

       }
```

Так же есть метод renderBox,который обновляет форму,если какой-то клиент подключился или отключился

```
public void renderBox()
        {
          


            listBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var Item in listClient)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(Item.name + " " + Item.id);
            }
            listBox.Refresh();
        }
```

Проблема в том,что это работает только с одним клиентом последовательно, второй обслуживается лишь тогда,когда уйдет первый. Я попробовал вынести прослушивание клиента в отдельный метод,который я уже скидывал выше( listenClient() ), а в главном методе start сервера написал вот так:

```
public void start()
        {
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
            tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                
                Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listenClient));
                myThread.Start();





            }

                   
        }
```

Моя логика заключается в следующем: клиент будет прослушиваться в своем потоке, и следующему не придется ждать разрыв соединения с предыдущим. Пытаюсь проверить и получаю такую ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я раньше никогда не работал с потоками, поэтому прошу вашей помощи. Как все это правильно распараллелить и реализовать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: У вас смешались кони, люди и при этом хвост виляет собакой. Почему сервер создает UI? Почему бы UI не опрашивать сервер? Сама проблема у вас в том, что операции с UI элементами могут выполняться только в том потоке, где эти элементы были созданы. Подобных просблем тут на сайте полно, просто воспользуйтесь поиском. Но я бы посоветовал перепродумать свю архитектуру.

Comment: `Я раньше никогда не работал с потоками, поэтому прошу вашей помощи` - [Начните читать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). Потоки: [1](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml), [2](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading2.xml), [на английском](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: Сделайте сервер консольным, пусть он пишет логи на экран и в файл, это самое простое решение. А клиенты делайте уж как вам нравится.